# Which partition should I install on on a Dell XPS 13?

Tags: installation, partitioning, dell, xps

I just bought the dell ultrabook xps 13, but I have some difficulties to install ubuntu 12.04.

Problem is about Hard-Disk partition.
Actually, the sda has already 4 part :

[image]

and I don't want delete the wrong part ...

This is the information from windows :

sda1 = OEM (100% free according windows, 33MB used on 41MB according linux ...)

sda2 = RECOVERY

sda3 = windows7

sda4 = standBy extended (hibernation) (100% free according windows, unknown according linux)

I think I should avoid to delete windows7 or RECOVERY, then it's between sda1 and sd4.
Fact is that I don't know what is OEM and hibernation seem pretty useful ...

If you have an idea or informations, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OEM is the partition that stores the bootmanager of windows 7. This drive enables you to boot from restore partition. (This occurs when you insert recovery disk)

You are correct you should not delete sda2 or sda3.

Thing I would recommend.

- Create the restore disk if not done already.
- Delete sda4. Right click and create a new extended partition. A extended partition is a wrapper to many logical partition.
- Inside that extended partition create a partition that will be used as `SWAP` partition.
- Create another partition to install ubuntu. With `/` as mount point.
- Rest place you can create more partition in ntfs. That will be accessible to both OS.

**NOTE: According to screenshot you are installing GRUB in sdb, make sure its correct**

Here is the partition scheme of mine (dell xps 15)

[image]

Comment: Can we still have hibernate option after deleting sda4 ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and yes it works smoothly, no problems with the dual boot. Here is procedure that I adapted:

1. With your bootable Ubuntu USB/CD select the option try Ubuntu and then run the Gparted partition manager.
2. First delete the Hibernation partition (don't worry it will not damange the existing windows OS or boot manager).
3. Next right click the unallocate free space and create an extended partition.
4. Within the extended partition create three logical partitions (home, root and swap), for the first two select ext4.
5. Now you need to assign mount points to these, you can use

   - sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   - and add the following lines:
   - /dev/sda5 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
   - /dev/sda6 / ext4 defaults 0 1
   - (replace /dev/sdaX with the corresponding location on your notebook).
6. Next you can proceed with actual installation (using the install icon in the left panel).
7. Choose install Ubuntu side-by-side with Windows and then select advanced partitioning for more control at the bottom of the next dialogue box. There you can control and direct ubuntu to use the 3 logical partitions you just created. Select and Edit each of them and in the "Use as" dropdown menu select ext4 journaling file system and under the "mount point" dropdown menu specify the corresponding mount points for home /home, for root / (here is a nice video of this that helped me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg)
8. Now you are ready to press install, you can confirm that installation will not touch the windows partition by selecting those windows partitions, click change and it should say: "do not use this parition" then press cancel.
   GOOD LUCK :)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid deleting **sda1**  ,it seems Windows reserved MBR , so **sda4** seems good enough for ubuntu installation.

From the image **sda4**  is 8.5 GB so you can reserve **2 GB for swap** space and remaining for **ROOT /** partition.

From the above image **MENU** , you can select that **sda4** partition to be **deleted**  *( don't worry just for allocation process)*, which will later show as **unallocated** , then **ADD** the **Unallocated** partition and  set the **SIZES** to create **swap and Root "/" (ext4)**  partitions .

From the last drop-down **Bootloader** menu  option select **SDA** not sdaX  for installing **Grub** . And you are good to go.

**Note :** Avoid storing large sums of DATA in Ubuntu  home partition , you may run out of memory soon enough :)