# Windows7 Gone after Ubuntu dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive

I had a very hard time to dual boot install Ubuntu 12.04
Apparently, Ubuntu has restriction of 4 partitions and I already had 4, so it just couldn't recognise my partitions. This was something I realised too late, but finally got to install Ubuntu.

Now, even though Windows 7 option is listed when I try to boot my laptop, it doesn't really let me boot and just loops back to begin. I tried windows repair DVD also, didn't work. I was fine with complete fresh install of windows too, but Windows CD didn't detect my Hard Disk Drive or any partitions (even though the original C drive with Windows is still an NTFS partition, according to gParted, and I can access the data from same using Ubuntu log in).
My Ubuntu works fine, but I need windows log in also. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info). This will give us clues for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Keep trying to load windows from the boot menu.

I had this problem too. However, I was getting the "Windows has recovered from an unexpected shutdown. . ."

I was given the option to either start in safe mode or start windows normally. Safe mode didn't work. I played the game a bit. I kept selecting windows on the boot screen and telling it to start windows normally. It took 10-11 tries (I was kinda stubborn.) But one of the times windows actually loaded. Once I got windows to load successfully once, I haven't had too much trouble with this again. I have been running both windows and Ubuntu successfully for about two weeks.

I would recommend being vigilant and just continuing to try to load windows repeatedly. If you can get it to load successfully once, then you shouldn't have too much trouble after that.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't have restriction of 4 partition. It is the dos partition table who poses this restriction.

Max 4 `primary` partition can be in a system. If you make one of them as extended partition, you can create many logical partition inside that and ubuntu can be installed in logical partition. [Read more here](https://askubuntu.com/a/151972/35775)

1. **I recommend you to get a back up of all files.**
2. Use a bootable partition manager tool like EASEUS partition manager.
3. Create a new layout like [this partition table](https://askubuntu.com/a/165943/35775)
4. If you have  your data in one of those partition, you can easily convert it to extended without any data loss.

Post a screenshot of your current partition table for more help.